# How to get the value from a textbox of a form popup

Tags: php, jquery, textbox, popup

How to get the value from a textbox of a form popup JQuery in PHP.

Here's my web [page](http://hoangnguyen1612.byethost4.com/#inline_content).

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
$("#inline_content table").find("#makhachhang").val(); // by this get id value in your form and same rest 

  $("#inline_content table").find(".tdthemkhachhang").val(); // by this get name value in your form and same rest 

$("#inline_content table :radio :selected").val(); // by this get radio value in your form and same rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#makhachhang").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data from textbox with PHP, you'll need put the HTML code inside a form, and send the data via GET or POST.

I recommend you to get the data via Javascript.

```
$("#inline_content table").find("#makhachhang");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
if input is like that:

$("#IdOfYourInput").val() will return the containt

Comment: yes. thank you for your help, I also think get value by javascript but i think about security problem, so i'm finding how to use form to send value

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just add an action attribute to your form and name attribute to your inputs.

```
<form action="your php file">
  <input name="email" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then on your php file, get it with:

```
$email = $_POST['email']
```

I suggest you learn the basics first:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp